# Fetch past 7 days in DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have a project where I need to analyze the data on dynamodb.

DynamoDB allows me to fetch data but not all of it and
I'm required to fetch around 7 days of data (currently it fetch just 2 days - around 1400 records)

```
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('IMEI').eq('xxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    Limit=10000
)
items = response['Items']
```

**These are the keys:**

- Primary partition key IMEI (String)
- Primary sort key  RecordingStartTime (String)

My goal is to fetch all the data uploaded during the past 7 days.

Thanks!

Comment: To achieve this you need to have sort key containing the timestamp (when the data is inserted) for every entry. With this you can retrieve whatever data you want based on the sort key.

Comment: Im trying to run this query using the sort key :          
KeyConditionExpression=Key('IMEI').eq('xxxxxxxxxx') & Key('RecordingStartTime').between(week_ago,today), and it still fetch only 1 day

Comment: is RecordingStartTime stored in a ISO 8601 format?

Comment: Adding on to @HoratiuJeflea make sure your dates are in ISO format to eliminate any ambiguity present

Comment: I don't have any presence of ambiguity, I'm fetching dates as a string because RecordingStartTime is a string, I've already completed the project using 1000 records, but the purpose of it is to run over a 100k + so I'm kinda stuck with the AWS query

Comment: Is it exactly giving data of one day? I mean when you query dynamodb there is a limit of 1MB per request so that might be also the reason. Just check it and tell me.

Comment: yes but also not all of the data from the same date, the first value : 0, 2020-06-23 00:00:27, 1234003  , and
last value : 1492, 2020-06-23 06:13:27, 1234003

Comment: So, did you check whether that data exceeds 1 MB or not. If it exceeds 1 MB then that might be the problem

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've checked and it is 13KB